# Make Sublime Text bookmarks column-insensitive

Tags: sublimetext3

How do I limit the bookmarks to be a single one per-line and not defined by a line and a column?

You know, like every other text editor.

Comment: which plug-in do you use?

Comment: none ........................

Answer (score 2):

In order to obtain less granularity in bookmark positions you need to replace the internal `toggle_bookmark` command with one that always forces the bookmarked position to be the start of whatever line the cursor is on instead of it's exact location.

For simplicity, that would look something like the following:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ToggleBookmarkCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view

        old = view.get_regions("bookmarks")
        new = [sublime.Region(view.line(sel.b).begin()) for sel in view.sel()]

        for sel in new:
            if sel not in old:
                old.append(sel)
            else:
                del old[old.index(sel)]

        view.add_regions("bookmarks", old, "bookmarks", "bookmark", sublime.PERSISTENT)
```

Placing this in a plugin in your `User` package will replace the internal `toggle_bookmark` command with this version, which will perform the appropriate toggle but always constrain the bookmark position to the start of the line instead.

The `bookmarks` region is the region that's used by the internal commands that work with bookmarks, so this command will work alongside any other commands that work with native bookmarks. This includes the commands that already exist to navigate between commands as well as those added by other plugins for extended functionality such as selecting between the current cursor position and the next bookmark (although in this case the facility of that may be somewhat less due to the positioning involved).

Comment: It works fine, except that it didn't override the default toggle_bookmark command. So I renamed the command to toggle_bookmark2 (ToggleBookmark2Command) and changed the key binding. Installation hint: the plugin file should have a .py extension.
Thanks

Comment: If the file is changed externally, then the bookmark positions change and won't be at the beginning of the line anymore.